# CSS, centering elements in the nav

Tags: html, css

Simple question, what's wrong? I've got menu and logo and I can't center this. I don't know why.

My CSS code:

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #515963;
}

#header #logo {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 80px;
  line-height: 104px;
}

#header nav .menuItem {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
}

#header nav .menuItem .item {
  cursor: pointer;

#header #logo {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
  }
  #header nav {
    clear: both;
    width: 369px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 104px;
  }
  #header nav .menuItem {
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="AFP"/></a>
      <nav>
        <div class="menuItem item1"><span class="item">kontakt</span></div>
        <div class="menuItem item2"><span class="item">produkty</span></div>
        <div class="menuItem item3"><span class="item">o nas</span></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </nav>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
```

and what I've got:

[image]

I'm using **div**s in nav because I like do it this way. I want the logo and the menu to be centered. I know the **width** and I don't understand why `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work.

Edit:

I want to reach such thing:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's there. My bad, I'll put it in the code above

Comment: The code you have provided produces nothing like your screen shot. Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: You need to combine your code in to _one_ snippet so that we can actually run it and see the result.

Comment: You are creating a mobile design?

Comment: Yes, but this is a bit different situation and and I need to do this that way

Comment: Can you put an image from what you want.

Comment: Floats and centering do not work well together. If you want your logo to be centered, center it, don't float it left. Similarly, if you want your nav to be centered, don't float it right.

Comment: I know, but in a desktop view I need it to be on the left side and in this view I want it to be centered

Comment: For this you need to use media query.

Comment: I am using it, but I can't center those dives, That's all, it's too easy to go wrong but it does

Comment: See my answer and say me if it need some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple error. You need id not tag http://joxi.ru/eAOYEqBuxvRD9m

Comment: Please don't link to an external source of code (or whatever is at the end of the link; as a security measure, I don't click links to domains I don't know). Include any code in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this situations is flexbox.

```css
#header{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;   
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#header #logo
{
  width:100px;
}
nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
}
nav div {
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/087039a00851e75ff483470e3aba89c9?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="AFP"/></a>
      <nav>
        <div class="menuItem item1"><span class="item">kontakt</span></div>
        <div class="menuItem item2"><span class="item">produkty</span></div>
        <div class="menuItem item3"><span class="item">o nas</span></div>
        
      </nav>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I edited the answer. Please see and let me know the result. In the answer i changed the image url.